# using mask rcnn with keras 2.4.3 on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, image-segmentation

I'm trying to run Mask-rcnn for metal defect detection (https://github.com/maxkferg/metal-defect-detection) on colab. The Keras version of colab is 2.4.3 whereas the repository keras version is 2.1.3. I get the following error in loading weights:

```
model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True, exclude=EXCLUDE_LAYER_WEIGHTS):
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a24cb8cfa577> in <module>()
----> 1 model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True, exclude=EXCLUDE_LAYER_WEIGHTS)

/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/metal-defect-detection/model.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name, exclude)
   2030 
   2031         if by_name:
-> 2032             topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, layers)
   2033 
   2034         else:

AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.topology' has no attribute 'load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name'
```

I tryied some solutions suggested on line such as: replace topology with saving but I have the same problem. There is a way to change the code in order to use such repository with keras 2.4.3?